# triangles in a grid of $n\times n$ with positive coordinates

Tags: triangles

I need to count the number of triangles formed in a grid of $n\times n$ with positive integer coordinates $(0..n)$. For example for $n = 1$ the answer is 4.

Comment: $0$ isn't a positive integer!

Comment: I think exact formula may be very hard. The problem is dealing with lines that pass through $3$ or more lattice points. This is sensitive to number-theoretic properties of $n$.

Comment: Calculate it for some small values of $n$, and look it up in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Comment: @Qiaochu, I have read that in France, zero is considered to be positive.